# Toolkit for making Windows Taskbar Tool Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, frameworks, toolkit

I'm making a small **tool application** that user can minimize in the **taskbar**. I'm sure I've seen a toolkit for it in some blog a few years ago. I'm basically just looking for a project template that perhaps has ready-made functionality for:

- minimizing to taskbar
- right-click menus
- animated small notification pop-up windows (like MS Messenger or Outlook)

Does anyone know if such a toolkit or framework exists?

/Pompair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.developer.com/article.php/3336751

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/trayiconmenu01.aspx

http://alperguc.blogspot.com/2008/11/c-system-tray-minimize-to-tray-with.html

I doubt any toolkit exists. This is rather easy to do.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/shelltray.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/notifyiconcontrol20.aspx